# Postfix Error Recipient address rejected: unverified address: mail transport unavailable when its With Ciphermail

Tags: email, encryption, dovecot, postfix-mta

i'm setting up a mail server [postfix] which with use Ciphermail as RelayHost.
With the setup i'm able to send mail to external domain but when i'm replying from external domain i'm getting following error.

[image]

ciphermail [relay host] main.cf

```html
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = djigzo:[127.0.0.1]:10025
djigzo_after_filter_message_size_limit = 512000000
djigzo_before_filter_message_size_limit = 10240000
djigzo_mailbox_size_limit = 512000000
djigzo_mydestination = localhost, svitsolutions.in, mx1.svitsolutions.in
djigzo_myhostname = mx1.svitsolutions.in
djigzo_mynetworks = 103.246.45.0/24, 192.168.15.0/24, 192.168.15.52/32
djigzo_parent_domain_matches_subdomains = relay_domains
djigzo_rbl_clients =
djigzo_reject_unverified_recipient = reject
djigzo_relay_domains = svitsolutions.in
djigzo_relay_transport_host = mail.svitsolutions.in
djigzo_relay_transport_host_mx_lookup =
djigzo_relay_transport_host_port = 25
djigzo_relayhost =
djigzo_relayhost_mx_lookup = mx
djigzo_relayhost_port = 25
djigzo_smtp_helo_name = mail.svitsolutions.in
djigzo_unverified_recipient_reject_code = 450
local_recipient_maps =
local_transport = $mydestination
mail_name = mx1.svitsolutions.in
mailbox_size_limit = ${djigzo_mailbox_size_limit}
message_size_limit = ${djigzo_after_filter_message_size_limit}
mydestination = ${djigzo_mydestination}, mail.svitsolutions.in, svitsolutions.in
myhostname = ${djigzo_myhostname}
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, [::1]/128, ${djigzo_mynetworks}
parent_domain_matches_subdomains = ${djigzo_parent_domain_matches_subdomains}
queue_minfree = 768000000
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = ${djigzo_relay_domains}
relay_transport = relay${djigzo_relay_transport_host?:${djigzo_relay_transport_host_mx_lookup:[}${djigzo_relay_transport_host}${djigzo_relay_transport_host_mx_lookup:]}:${djigzo_relay_transport_host_port}}
relayhost = ${djigzo_relayhost_mx_lookup:${djigzo_relayhost?[}}${djigzo_relayhost}${djigzo_relayhost_mx_lookup:${djigzo_relayhost?]}}${djigzo_relayhost?:${djigzo_relayhost_port}}
smtp_helo_name = ${djigzo_smtp_helo_name?$djigzo_smtp_helo_name}${djigzo_smtp_helo_name:${myhostname}}
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.1/32, 192.168.15.52/32
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_discard_ehlo_keywords = silent-discard, dsn, etrn
smtpd_etrn_restrictions = reject
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination ${djigzo_rbl_clients} ${djigzo_reject_unverified_recipient? reject_unverified_recipient}
unverified_recipient_reject_code = ${djigzo_unverified_recipient_reject_code}
```

When im removing the relay host [ciphermail] from architecture i'm able to  receive mail from external domain.

please suggest the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have enabled "Reject unverified recipient". The 450 error message reports that the recipient address cannot be verified. The default Postfix configuration for CipherMail is that Postfix will function as a store and forward server and no local mailboxes. However you have configured mydestination (indirectly by setting djigzo_mydestination) to locally handle mail for svitsolutions.in but you also configured relay_domains (indirectly by setting djigzo_relay_domains) to svitsolutions.in.

With the current config, email sent to svitsolutions.in will be handled by the local transport (which will then store the email locally). However in the default Postfix master.cf config, the local transport is disabled because in the default config, email should not be locally stored. Because the local transport is not available, the recipient verification will fail.

If you want to store email locally you should re-enable the local transport (see main.cf and master.cf) and make sure that a local user is available. If you do not want to store mail locally on the system but only act as a relaying server, set djigzo_mydestination and mydestination to an empty value.

Comment: thanks . I wanted it to relay the incoming mails to mail  server. I removed the value of **djigzo_mydestination** and **mydestination** and my mails are recieving by mail box perfectly fine